# Javascript module management in Django (closed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I am working on a project that has multiple .js file for containing different functions.
I want to use the function from M1.js in M2.js and what I am doing is exporting the function from M1.js and importing in M2.js.

The export works fine, but the issue is when I import function.

```
M1.js
--export {function}

M2.js
--import {function} from './M1.js'

<script type="module" href="{% static 'myapp/M1.js'%}
<script type="module" href="{% static 'myapp/M2.js'%}
```

Above is the code that generate following error on import

```
Loading module from “app.com/static/Invoicing/exif_js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

My directory structure is

```
-Project
 |--project
 |--Invoicing (App)
   |--static
     |--Invoicing
       |--M1.js
       |--M2.js
   |--templates
   |--etc
 |--static
 |--etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the base href in `index.html` to the current directory

Change this

```
<base href="/">
```

to this

```
<base href="./">
```

Comment: The issue was the path I was using to import the module, BTW thanks for your input